# create and write to a .pgm file with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I'm wondering if there is a way to create and write to an Portable ASCII P2 Graymap file with the FileOutputStream class. (I need to use this class)

This is what I did so far but I think it is wrong because I cant open the file with this viewer:
https://smallpond.ca/jim/photomicrography/pgmViewer/index.html

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){    
           
        try{    
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("picture.pgm");
             //create .pgm header
             //P2
             fos.write('P');  
             fos.write('2'); 
             //500x200 pixel
             fos.write(500);   
             fos.write(200);  
        
             //create black image
             for(int i=0; i< 500; i++){
                for(int k=0; k< 200; k++){
                    fos.write(0);
                } 
             }
             
            fos.close();    
                    
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }    
      }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use `.write()` hoping to write an ASCII formatted decimal numbers, but it instead outputs a byte. This is immediately obvious if you open the file in a text editor.

You are further neglecting to include a grayscale depth, and you are missing whitespace between the numbers.

To write text to a file, it's easier to use a `PrintStream`:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        try{
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("picture.pgm");
             PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

             ps.println("P2");
             ps.println("500 200");
             // Expect gray values between 0 and 255 inclusive
             ps.println("255");

             for(int i=0; i< 500; i++){
                for(int k=0; k< 200; k++){
                    ps.print(0);
                    // Separate numbers by space
                    ps.print(" ");
                }
                // Make each image line a separate text line for
                // easier viewing in a text editor
                ps.println();
             }

            ps.close();

            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
      }
}
```